# Parsing single line and multi line comments with Arpeggio

Tags: python, python-3.x, peg, arpeggio

I'm trying to use Arpeggio to parse file containing single line and multi line comments.

Arpeggio's documentation suggests to have a look at their "simple" example to see how to deal with them (see [documentation](https://textx.github.io/Arpeggio/2.0/configuration/#comment-handling) and [linked code](https://github.com/textX/Arpeggio/blob/master/examples/simple/simple.py)). The example indeed includes the following definition:

```
def comment():          return [_(r"//.*"), _(r"/\*.*\*/")]
```

which is used by the parser as follows:

```
parser = ParserPython(simpleLanguage, comment, debug=debug)
```

Unfortunately, however, their example doesn't contain any comment so it's not really possible to see how it works. If I add the following dummy comments to the example:

```
/*
This is a multi-line comment.
*/
// This is a single-line comment.
function fak(n) {
...
```

then the following exception is raised:

```
arpeggio.NoMatch: Expected '//.*' or keyword at position (1, 1) => '*/* This is'.
```

which seems to suggest the example file doesn't match the comment rule nor keyword `function` that is the first token that the production of `simpleLanguage` allows.

Does anyone know how we are supposed to deal with comments?

Please find below a MRE if it helps debugging the problem:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import os

from arpeggio import *
from arpeggio import RegExMatch as _


def comment():  return [_(r"//.*"), _(r"/\*.*\*/")]
def document(): return Kwd("hello"), _(r"[a-z]+"), '!', EOF


def main(filename, debug=False):
    current_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    content = open(os.path.join(current_dir, filename), "r").read()
    parser = ParserPython(document, comment, debug=debug)
    parse_tree = parser.parse(content)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main('simple.ex', debug=True)
```

and the content of the file to parse:

```
/*
This is a multi-line comment.
*/
// This is a single line comment.
hello world!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version of the `comment()` method does not handle line breaks very well. It might work if you try to adjust it like this, to include both whitespace and non-whitespace characters:

```py
def comment():  return [_(r"//.*"), _(r"/\*[\s\S]*?\*/")]
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks... is this something to report to Arpeggio's team?

Comment: You could create an issue on their GitHub repo and then also give them the altered code and maybe even create a pull request. Then the devs can decide how to handle it.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this issue up. I've fixed Arpeggio example.